# How do I get the name of a property from a property in C# (2.0)

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I know I could have an attribute but that's more work than I want to go to... and not general enough.

I want to do something like

```
class Whotsit
{
    private string testProp = "thingy";

    public string TestProp 
    {
        get { return testProp; }
        set { testProp = value; }
    }

}

...

Whotsit whotsit = new Whotsit();
string value = GetName(whotsit.TestProp); //precise syntax up for grabs..
```

where I'd expect value to equal "TestProp"

but I can't for the life of me find the right reflection methods to write the GetName method...

EDIT: Why do I want to do this? I have a class to store settings read from a 'name', 'value' table. This is populated by a generalised method based upon reflection. I'd quite like to write the reverse...

```
/// <summary>
/// Populates an object from a datatable where the rows have columns called NameField and ValueField. 
/// If the property with the 'name' exists, and is not read-only, it is populated from the 
/// valueField. Any other columns in the dataTable are ignored. If there is no property called
/// nameField it is ignored. Any properties of the object not found in the data table retain their
/// original values.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the object to be populated.</typeparam>
/// <param name="toBePopulated">The object to be populated</param>
/// <param name="dataTable">'name, 'value' Data table to populate the object from.</param>
/// <param name="nameField">Field name of the 'name' field'.</param>
/// <param name="valueField">Field name of the 'value' field.</param>
/// <param name="options">Setting to control conversions - e.g. nulls as empty strings.</param>

public static void PopulateFromNameValueDataTable<T>
        (T toBePopulated, System.Data.DataTable dataTable, string nameField, string valueField, PopulateOptions options)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        bool nullStringsAsEmptyString = options == PopulateOptions.NullStringsAsEmptyString;

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            string name = dataRow[nameField].ToString();
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(name);
            object value = dataRow[valueField];

            if (property != null)
            {
                Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
                if (nullStringsAsEmptyString && (propertyType == typeof(String)))
                {
                    value = TypeHelper.EmptyStringIfNull(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    value = TypeHelper.DefaultIfNull(value, propertyType);
                }

                property.SetValue(toBePopulated, System.Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyType), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

FURTHER EDIT: I am just in code, have an instance of Whotsit and I want to get the text string of the 'TestProp' property. It seems kind of weird I know, I can just use the literal "TestProp" - or in the case of my  class to datatable function I'd be in a foreach loop of PropertyInfos. I was just curious...

The original code had string constants, which I found clumsy.

Comment: See <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855337/referring-to-the-property-itself-in-c-reflection-generic-type">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855337/referring-to-the-property-itself-in-c-reflection-generic-type</a>

Comment: You might have an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1225702/661933

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's nothing to do this. The expression `whotsit.TestProp` will evaluate the property. What you want is the mythical "infoof" operator:

```
// I wish...
MemberInfo member = infoof(whotsit.TestProp);
```

As it is, you can only use reflection to get the property by name - not from code. (Or get all the properties, of course. It still doesn't help you with your sample though.)

One alternative is to use an expression tree:

```
Expression<Func<string>> = () => whotsit.TestProp;
```

then examine the expression tree to get the property.

If none of this helps, perhaps you could tell us more about why you want this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible (without reflection) but only with latest C# 3.0

**quick & very very dirty**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string propertyName = GetName(() => AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
        Console.WriteLine(propertyName); // prints "CurrentDomain"
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string GetName(Expression<Func<object>> property)
    {
        return property.Body.ToString().Split('.').Last();
    }
}
```

**Update:** I've just realized that [**Jon Skeet**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts) (anyone surprised? :) has covered this possibility already but I'll keep my answer here just in case someone is interested in some example to start with.

Comment: Also needs .NET 3.5 (OP states 2.0)

Comment: I know but it's good generic question and someone with .NET 3.5 might be interested in this.

Comment: I agree, not much use to me, but maybe of use to others who come looking.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.  Using reflection you can:

- Get a property, field or method's details from it's string name.
- Get a list of all properties, fields or methods for a given type.

Your GetName method, when called, is passed a string.  The GetMethod will know about the string but retains no source property meta data.

Out of interest, why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, the only way to do this is to iterate over properties:

```
class TestClass
{
    private string _field;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _field; }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        PropertyInfo[] info = test.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(PropertyInfo i in info)
            Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: which still won't give me the ability to get the name of a property from an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Kpollack, you said in an earlier comment:

> which still won't give me the ability to get the name of a property from an instance of it.

This leads me to believe that you somehow have a reference to a property. How did you get this reference? What is its type? Could you provide a code sample? If it's a PropertyInfo object, you already have what you need; since this doesn't appear to be the case, we're dealing with something else, and I'd be very interested to see what it is that you *do* have to work with.

P.S. Forgive me for seeming obtuse: it's early, I haven't had enough coffee, and I don't have my IDE in front of me. :-/

Comment: I am just in code, have an instance of Whotsit and I want to get the text string of the 'TestProp' property. It seems kind of weird I know, I can just use the literal "TestProp" - or in the case of my  class to datatable function I'd be in a foreach loop of PropertyInfos. I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I tried to serialize it to see if, by chance, that contains the property name, but no luck.

Non-working code below:

```
Whotsit w = new Whotsit();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(w.TestProp.GetType());
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\TestProp.xml");
xs.Serialize(sw, w.TestProp);
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

The [GetProperties on the Type class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) will give you the list of properties on that type.

```
Type t = whotsit.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pis = t.GetProperties();
```

Comment: true, but not much use for what I want to do since it is the string of the name that I am after...