# Retrieving attributes from a function argument

Tags: reflection, f#, attributes

If I have a function that takes in another function:

```
[<SomeAttribute()>]
let f (g:unit->unit) =
    //Want to get g's custom attributes
```

How can I access g's custom attributes from f?

I think I'm missing something really obvious here.

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575180/retrieve-methodinfo-of-a-f-function  (What you want doesn't seem to be possible unless you know the assembly and the name of the function.)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wonder if I should close/delete this question then since it's obviously a duplicate?

Comment: I think you can accept Tomas's answer. I'm using same approach too (after trying to hack the CIL, which doesn't work in release mode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not in general possible, because when you use a function as an argument (e.g. `f foo`), the F# compiler wraps the `foo` value into some object. Extracting the actual method reference `foo` from this object would be very difficult (and it would work only if the compiler didn't do some optimizations).

However, you can get the desired behavior using F# quotations. Instead of taking a function `unit -> unit`, your `f` can take a quoted function `Expr<unit -> unit>`. You can then call the function using `f <@ foo @>` and the function can extract the method refernce and also call `foo`.

Here is an example. It requires reference to F# PowerPack (so that it can evaluate the quotation). In this simple case, the evaluation should be quite efficient:

```
#r @"FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"

type SomeAttribute(name:string) =
  inherit System.Attribute()
  member x.Name = name

// Example function with some attribute
[<SomeAttribute("Test")>]
let g () = printfn "Hello"

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

// Takes a quotation instead of a function value
let f (g:Expr<unit->unit>) =
  // Extract method info & attributes from the quotation
  match g with
  | DerivedPatterns.Lambdas(_, Patterns.Call(_, mi, _)) ->
      let attrs = mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof<SomeAttribute>, false)
      for a in attrs |> Seq.cast<SomeAttribute> do
        printfn "%A" a.Name
  | _ -> 
      failwith "Argument must be of the form <@ foo @>!"

  // Compile the function so that it can be executed (the compilation
  // takes some time, but calling invoke should be fast)
  let invoke = g.Compile()()
  invoke()
  invoke()

// And this is how you call the function
f <@ g @>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let f (g:unit->unit) =
    printfn "%d" (g.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true).Count())
```

Comment: I think that this returns the type attributes and not the instance attributes (e.g. ReflectedDefinition will not appear).