# How can I get the name and value of a property using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this code and I am using it to raise the PropertyChanged event without passing the name of property to the function.

```
private void RaisePropertyChanged<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue>> propertySelector)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(memberExpression.Member.Name));
            }
        }
    }
```

and I am calling it in this way:

```
  this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsReady);
```

Which will raise the PropertyChanged event for the IsReady property. I like the idea as writing code in this way will help to change the name of the property very easily.

Now I want to use the same technique to pass the name and value of a property to a method. Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Do you want to pass a property of the calling class, or some other class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an expression tree to read the name and value of a property. Is there an alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835527/using-an-expression-tree-to-read-the-name-and-value-of-a-property-is-there-an-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have it:

```
string name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
TValue value = propertySelector.Compile()();
```

An alternative would be to look at the `member.MemberType`, cast to `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo` respectively:

```
var member = memberExpression.Member;
string name = member.Name;
object value;
switch(member.MemberType) {
    case MemberTypes.Field:
       value = ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(this);
       break;
    case MemberTypes.Property:
       value = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(this, null);
       break;
    default:
       throw new NotSupportedException(member.MemberType.ToString());
}
```

However, a *simpler* approach is... to simply *pass the name and value* to the method:

```
Foo("IsReady", IsReady);
```

It depends a bit on how efficient it needs to be, though (reflection/expression does add an overhead - whether that is *significant* depends on the context).

Answer (score 0):

For getting the name you can use `memberExpression.Member.Name` and for getting the value you could use `this.GetType().GetProperty (memberExpression.Member.Name).GetGetMethod().Invoke (this, null)`.